# Jquery changing focused input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, keyup

I am trying to make a system where when i fill a text box it moves onto the next.
Currently I have this code:

```
 $('#txt1').keyup(function() {
    if(this.value.length == $(this).attr('maxlength')) {
       $('#txt2').focus();
    }
 });
```

I want to make this continues so it will go on to echo `#txt3` `#txt4` ect.
Also would there be a way to change the focused text box via the arrow keys. E.G. when up arrow key is pressed selected is changed from `#txt4` to `#txt3` and the opposite for the down key.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMO this won't be user-friendly.

Comment: So when you hit the maximum number of characters allowed, move along, don't give the user any chance to delete characters or edit the input, just move on to the next one? I agree with @undefined, there's a reason you don't see this kinda thing ... anywhere !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code to address your first question. I added a class attribute for convenience and replaced the "maxlength" attribute by the HTML "size" attribute.

**HTML**

```
<p><input type="text" class="navigable" id="txt1" data-number="1" size="2" placeholder="dd"></p>
<p><input type="text" class="navigable" id="txt2" data-number="2" size="2" placeholder="mm"></p>      
<p><input type="text" class="navigable" id="txt3" data-number="3" size="4" placeholder="yyyy"></p>
```

**JS**

```
$('.navigable').keyup(function() {
var self = $(this);
var next = $('#txt'+(self.data('number')+1));
if(next.length > 0 && self.val().length == self.attr('size')) {
   next.focus();
}
```

});

[You can try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wUzP/1/)

I have my doubts concerning your request about the arrow keys binding. What happens if the user wants to navigate in one of the inputs? Nevertheless, here is the code to take into account the arrow keys:

**HTML**

```
<p><input type="text" class="navigable" id="txt1" data-number="1" size="2" placeholder="dd"></p>
<p><input type="text" class="navigable" id="txt2" data-number="2" size="2" placeholder="mm"></p>
<p><input type="text" class="navigable" id="txt3" data-number="3" size="4" placeholder="yyyy"></p>
```

**JS**

```
$('.navigable').keyup(function(e) {
  var self = $(this);
  var currentInput = self.data('number');
  var next = $('#txt'+ (currentInput + 1));
  var previous = $('#txt'+ (currentInput - 1));
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(next.length && keyCode === 40)
      next.focus();
  else if(previous.length && keyCode === 38)
      previous.focus();
  else if(next.length && self.val().length == self.attr('size')) {
     next.focus();
  }
```

});

[You can try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/9wUzP/3/)

Comment: Thanks, This is what I am looking for. The problem is i want the name to be a ID from a DB that is not ordered ID. Is there a way for the next item to be decided from something like 'data-next'

Comment: Yeah sure, you can. But to help you find the best solution I need a little bit more info. Are the inputs part of the same div? This could enable us to use the jQuery :eq instead of relying on data-* attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a keypress event which checks for the key pressed and based on the key pressed take necessary action!
**EDIT**: You can know which key was pressed by passing a parameter in your function call

```
.keypress(function(e))
{
    if(e.which == 13)
       //take necessary action for enter key
    etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks, shall try that

Answer (score 1):

Bind a `keydown` event and check for the proper `event.which`:

- Left: 37
- Up: 38
- Right: 39
- Down: 40